# How to add authentication to react router

Tags: reactjs

This is what I have:

```
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/auth" render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/index" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

As you can see, you can go both to all the pages under "admin" and "auth" without any auth check.
The files under the folder "layouts/" have both an:

```
import routes from "routes.js";
```

And (a part from layout data) respectively:

```
<Switch>
  {getRoutes(routes)}
  <Redirect from="*" to="/admin/index" />
</Switch>
```

and

```
<Switch>
  {getRoutes(routes)}
  <Redirect from="*" to="/auth/login" />
</Switch>
```

The router.js contains this:

```
import Index from "views/Index.js";
import Login from "views/examples/Login.js";
import Tables from "views/examples/Tables.js";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/index",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "ni ni-tv-2 text-primary",
    component: Index,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/tables",
    name: "Tables",
    icon: "ni ni-bullet-list-67 text-red",
    component: Tables,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    icon: "ni ni-key-25 text-info",
    component: Login,
    layout: "/auth",
  },
];
export default routes;
```

To add authentication I followed this guide:

```
https://www.nicknish.co/blog/react-router-authenticated-routes
```

So I added this in index.js:

```
export const fakeAuth = {
    signedIn: false
};

const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
        if (!fakeAuth.signedIn) {
            return <Redirect to="/auth/login" />;
        }

        return children;
};
```

However, what it happens it that, no matter what url I go to, I will always be redirected to this:

```
http://localhost:3003/auth/login
```

And the problem is that the page is completely empty with no errors in the console. The login-page is not rendered for some reason. And it does not look as I went inside an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
export const fakeAuth = {
  signedIn: false,
};
```

As the name of the variable indicates, this is just mocking authentication. `fakeAuth` never changes in your code so this:

```
if (!fakeAuth.signedIn) {
  return <Redirect to="/auth/login" />;
}
```

will always evaluate to `true`. Meaning you will always stay on the login page.

---

So you need to create a mechanism that is able to track and update authentication / authorization status.

As far as authentication and authorization goes there are many ways to go about it. I would setup a backend application that your React app could send requests to, to authorize / authenticate users.

However you decide to handle the actual authentication / authorization you probably also want to use something like [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist login status across refreshes.

For this you could create custom a hook something like this:

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") ? true : false
  );

  // For your actual application you will need to refactor this
  // based on your authentication / authorization implementation,
  // user input, etc...
  const handleLogin = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
    setIsSignedIn(true);
  };

  return { isSignedIn, handleLogin };
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// Other imports...
import { useAuth } from "./router";

const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
  const { isSignedIn } = useAuth();
  if (!isSignedIn) {
    return <Redirect to={LOGIN_URL} />;
  }

  return children;
};
```

and this:

```
// Other imports...
import { useAuth } from "./router";

const Login = () => {
  const { isSignedIn, handleLogin } = useAuth();
  if (isSignedIn) {
    return <Redirect to={DASHBOARD_URL} />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Login to access Dashboard</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleLogin()}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you but thats not really correct. The link I provided shows a working solution, even though there is a fakeLogin. My problem is that the page is completely blank, no matter if I use his or your solution.

Comment: Can you update your code so the problem is reproducible? Here's [my forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-authentication-router-forked-bzyw2?file=/src/router.js) based on the guide.

Comment: What I did was to download this bootstrap for react: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-dashboard-react. And then just add the code you wrote above.